# error in downloading using ascp

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-13.10

I am trying to downloading some file using this command:

using both SRA toolkit and Aspera Connect

```
~/source/sratoolkit.2.3.5-2-ubuntu64/bin/prefetch -t ascp -a "~/.aspera/connect/bin/ascp|~/.aspera/connect/etc/asperaweb_id_dsa.openssh" SRR1287825
```

but It gives me this error

```
1) Downloading 'SRR1287825'...
Downloading via fasp...
err: process failed while waiting process - ascp failed with 1
fasp download failed
1) failed to download SRR1287825
```

what is the meaning of error 1 , and what shall I do?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it the command was not able to solve ~/ I need to put the full path for example /home/user-name/.aspera